# solve $t^{2}u''+tu'+(t^{2}-1)u=0$ using Laplace

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, bessel-functions

given the ode:$t^{2}u''+tu'+(t^{2}-1)u=0;u(0)=1,u'(0)=0$

solve with Laplace transform.

My try:
$t^{2}u''+tu'+(t^{2}-1)u=0\\Lu''=s^{2}Lu-1\\Lu'=sLu-1\\t^{2}(s^{2}Lu-1)+t(sLu-1)+(t^{2}-1)Lu=0\\t^{2}s^{2}Lu-t^{2}+tsLu-t+(t^{2}-1)Lu=0\\t^{2}s^{2}Lu+tsLu+(t^{2}-1)Lu=t^{2}+t\\Lu(t^{2}s^{2}+ts+t^{2}-1)=t^{2}+t\\Lu=\frac{t^{2}+t}{(t^{2}s^{2}+ts+t^{2}-1)}\\Lu=\frac{1}{1+s^{2}}+\frac{1+t-st+s^{2}t}{(1+s^{2})(-1+st+t^{2}+s^{2}t^{2})}$

which seems to be a dead end.
Edit:
I was able to find L(u)

$\begin{array}{c}
t^{2}u''+tu'+(t^{2}-1)u=0\\
Lt^{2}u''+Ltu'+Lt^{2}\text{u}-Lu=0\\
Lt^{2}u''+Ltu'+Lt^{2}\text{u}-Lu=0\\
(Lu'')''-(Lu')'+(Lu)''-Lu=0\\
u(0)=1,u'(0)=0\\
(Lu'')''-(Lu')'+(Lu)''-Lu=0\\
(s^{2}Lu-1)''-(sLu-1)'+(Lu)''-Lu=0\\
(s^{2}L''u+4sL'+2Lu)-(sL'u+Lu)+(L''u)-Lu=0\\
s^{2}L''u+4sL'+2Lu-sL'u-Lu+L''u-Lu=0\\
(s^{2}+1)L''u+3sL'=0\\
(x^{2}+1)\text{y''}+3xy'=0\\
y''+\frac{3x}{(x^{2}+1)}y'=0\\
z'+\frac{3x}{(x^{2}+1)}z=0\\
\frac{z'}{z}=-\frac{3x}{(x^{2}+1)}\\
\log|z|=-\frac{3}{2}log(1+x^{2})+c\\
z=c(1+x^{2})^{-\frac{3}{2}}\\
y'=c(1+x^{2})^{-\frac{3}{2}}\\
Lu=y=c_{1}+\frac{c_{2}x}{\sqrt{x^{2}+1}}
\end{array}$

Comment: You shouldn't have any $t$ in the transformed equation.  You seem to be assuming that $L(t^2 u) = t^2L(u).$   Check your Laplace table for a formula for $L(t f(t)).$

Comment: @B.Goddard can you say which transition is not legit?

Comment: You can't have t variable once you have applied Laplace transform

Comment: thanks, can you solve this question? @Aryadeva

Answer (score 2):

$$t^{2}u''+tu'+(t^{2}-1)u=0$$
$$u(0)=1,u'(0)=0$$
You can't keep the $t$ variable once you have applied the Laplace transform.

Laplace transform of $t^2u''$ is:
$$L t^2u''=\dfrac {d^2}{ds^2}Lu''=\dfrac {d^2}{ds^2}(s^2U(s))-su'(0)-u(0))$$
$$L t^2u''=\dfrac {d^2}{ds^2}(s^2U(s))-su'(0))$$
$$L t^2u''=\dfrac {d^2}{ds^2}(s^2U(s))$$
And:
$$L tu'=-\dfrac {d}{ds}Lu'=-\dfrac {d}{ds}(sU(s)-u(0))$$
$$=-\dfrac {d}{ds}(sU(s))=-(U(s)+sU'(s))$$
The Lapalce transform of the last term of the ifferential equation:
$$L(t^2-1)u=-U(s)+\dfrac {d^2}{ds^2}(U(s))$$
$$=-U(s)+U''(s)$$

Note that the DE is Bessel's differential equation of order $1$. Not that easy to solve with Laplace Transform. Take a look [here](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/people/dobrush/am33/Mathematica/ch6/bessel.html)